# What is the correct way of including files/directories in Fay?

Tags: haskell, fay

I am trying to compile haskell to JS using Fay with one directory after the `--include` option like so:

`fay --include src\Tmv src\Tmv\Client\Main.hs`

There is a SharedTypes.hs file in src\Tmv which defines a module `Tmv.SharedTypes` that is used in Client\Main.hs. I get the following error:

```
Could not find module "Tmv.SharedTypes". Use -v to see a list of files searched for.
```

The -v option does not work. I have tried several variations of the parameters, eg. absolute paths, quotation marks, escaped (double) backslashes.
Configuration: fay 0.10.1.0, ghc 7.4.2 (i386), Windows 7 x64

Comment: Have you tried either including just `src`, or moving `SharedTypes.hs` into a `Tmv` subdirectory? If it's using the same rules as GHC, a module `Foo.Bar` is expected to be `Bar.hs` in a subdirectory `Foo` of whatever "root" directory it starts from.

Comment: C. A. McCann, including just `src` works. Didn't know that about GHC Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving this from a comment, since it apparently resolved the problem:

When GHC looks for source files, normally it expects a module `Foo.Bar` to be found as `Bar.hs` in a subdirectory `Foo`, relative to whatever "root" directory it starts from. For example, if you start GHCi with `Foo` as the current directory, you'll have problems with the module `Bar` either not being found, or errors because the module name won't match what GHC expects.

Since the same rules seem to be in play in your case, to import `Tmv.SharedTypes` you want `SharedTypes.hs` to be in a `Tmv` subdirectory of whatever the base path is, so either creating another `Tmv` subdirectory or specifying `src` alone for `--include` should work.